# Merging object arrays in powershell, can I make it faster?

Tags: powershell, performance

I finally got a function working to combine object arrays and all of their different properties.

```
function CombineObjects($ObjArrayOne, $ObjArrayTwo, $Identifier)
{
    # Initialize properties
    $Props = @()

    # We need a list of properties from each array
    $ObjArrayOne, $ObjArrayTwo | ForEach-Object {
        $Props += $_ | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    }

    # Initialize variables
    $OneID = $null
    $TwoID = $null

    # Loop through the properties and find those containing "Name"
    foreach ($prop in $Props) {
        if ($prop -match $Identifier) {
            if ($OneID -eq $null) {
                $OneID = $prop
            } else {
                $TwoID = $prop
            }
        }
    }

    $CombinedArray = @()

    # Combine the arrays based on matching identifiers
    foreach ($item in $ObjArrayOne) {
        $matchingItem = $ObjArrayTwo | Where-Object { $_.$TwoID -eq $item.$OneID }
        write-host "So $matchingItem is array two and $item.$OneID is array one"
        if ($matchingItem -ne $null) {
            $TempObject = [PSCustomObject]@{}

            foreach ($prop in $Props) {
                if ($item.$prop -ne $null) {
                    $TempObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $prop -Value $item.$prop
                } elseif ($matchingItem.$prop -ne $null) {
                    $TempObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $prop -Value $matchingItem.$prop
                }
            }

            $CombinedArray += $TempObject
        }
    }

    # Return the combined array
    return $CombinedArray
}

#Call Function
$CombinedResult = CombineObjects $ObjectArray1 $ObjectArray2 "Name"
```

For Example:

```
1_Description : Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard
1_IP          : 10.10.10.10
1_Name        : SERVER1002
1_OS          : Server 2019
```

and

```
2_Activity    : Active
2_Name        : SERVER1002
2_Type        : Computer
```

Will become:

```
1_Description : Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard
1_IP          : 10.10.10.10
1_Name        : SERVER1002
1_OS          : Server 2019
2_Activity    : Active
2_Name        : SERVER1002
2_Type        : Computer
```

No matter how many different properties there are it combines them all into one list. It seems like my script here is very long and slow to run. Are there any obvious ways I could make it faster? I am new to powershell.

I have tried to change the `Where-Object { $_.$TwoID -eq $item.$OneID }` line, but I can seem to use anything else without breaking my function...

Comment: how should this function handle possible collision between properties ?

Comment: The sample use case appears to show two objects - not two arrays?

Comment: You use `-match` as your property distinguisher. What happens when you have 1_Name and 1_OwningTeamname on the same object and `$Identifier = 'Name'`?

Comment: Make a hashtable of one of the arrays first.

Comment: Use a hashtable and [try avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is inefficiënt, see also: [In PowerShell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1848821/1701026), using this [`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule): `$ObjectArray1 | Join-Object $ObjectArray2 Name`.

Comment: As others have suggested, use a hashtable for faster lookups. Pipelining works for one liners or quick tasks, here you should use a loop. Finally, when using `+=` PowerShell has to create a new array, copy all the items over, and then add the new item. Use an `ArrayList` which has faster `.Add()` and `.Remove()` functions.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I will absolutely use hashtables and using  .Add and .Remove sounds like a good edit as well. I dont see a checkmark or option to select answer and close this thing. First post.... can we close this?